# Show: $\max_{|z|=R} \operatorname{Re}\left(z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right) \geq N $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined in a neighbourhood of $\overline{D(0,R)}$ which has no zero on $\partial D(0,R).$ Let $N$ be number of zeros of $f$ in $D(0,R).$

Show: $\max_{|z|=R} \operatorname{Re}\left(z\dfrac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}\right) \geq N \ $

My attempt: $\begin{align}\int_{|z|=R}\operatorname{Re}\left(z\dfrac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} \right) dz+ i\int_{|z|=R}\operatorname{Im}\left(z\dfrac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} \right)dz\end{align}=2\pi i \sum^{n}_{i=1}\alpha_{i} a_i,$ where $a_i$ is zero of $f$ and $\alpha_i$ is the corresponding multiplicity and $\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n = N.$

Could anyone advise me on how to proceed from here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$N=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f'(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}d\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

@Nirdonkey, thanks for the suggestion.

$\begin{align} \text{Hence, }\dfrac{1}{2 \pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \dfrac{f^{\prime}(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}d\theta= \dfrac{1}{2 \pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \text{Re}\left(\dfrac{f^{\prime}(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}\right)d\theta \leq 2\pi \dfrac{1}{2 \pi}\text{max} _{0 \leq \theta \leq  2\pi} \text{Re}\left(\dfrac{f^{\prime}(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}\right) = \text{max}_{|z|=R} \text{Re}\left(z\dfrac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}\right)\end{align}$